# How used the getrawtransaction for fin the tx blockchain

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

How used the getrawtransaction to find the tx blockchain?

inside the documentation says to use the -txindex, can you give me an example for the complete command please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start bitcoind just pass the `-txindex` flag in order to have it create the transaction index to be able to get any transaction by id:

```
bitcoind -txindex
```

In the console, you can get any raw transaction by its transaction id (hash):

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction
15f7c2c57cce37d9b8927f957840ec9367bb504780347e497c758ee022b2a143

...
```